# Custom regex for SSN

Tags: regex

Need a regex that will identify SSN so that we can mask the numbers, but want to skip masking of work order numbers (starts with WO-).

Details are below:

```
Current regex used: \b(?!000|666|9)\d{3}[- ]?(?!00)\d{2}[- ]?(?!0000)\d{4}\b
```

Sample Test Date

```
WO-011493479
011493479
778-62-8144
030 72 7381
757-85-7495
149-13-7317
401318448
003 06 8815
790714615
805 14 1893
```

From the above sample data, numbers after WO-*011493479* should be skipped. Due to the above regex, a work order string like WO-011493479 is getting changed to WO-*********.

For checking the regex quickly, please use this [link](https://regex101.com/r/BFmqZ9/1).

Note: The regex should work with all major browsers

Comment: So if it is preceded with `XO-011493479` then it should match?

Comment: It should not match if preceded with "WO-"

Comment: That "system" you are talking about, should it get a match only? Or if you provide a match and a capture group, it will take the capture group?

Comment: It should just match and ignore if the string starts with WO-

Comment: I think you can not do that without either using a lookbehind or a capture group with extra code.

Answer (score 1):

You're one negative look behind from getting it yourself:

```
\b(?<!WO-)(?!000|666|9)\d{3}[- ]?(?!00)\d{2}[- ]?(?!0000)\d{4}\b
```

Comment: "?<!" does not work in browsers like Safari, so do you have any alternate suggestion

Comment: Sure, use a simple `startsWith()` test to skip over some entries if you can't use the necessary level of regex.

Comment: Actually, it is a system which can not be customized hence need an exact regex that will work for all the browsers.